# Hello world on ruby and rails (ror)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, command-line, permissions

I've saved 'hello world' as a `.rb` file on my computer running Mac OS X Lion. I'm trying to create a new directory called `ruby_tutorials` in the root of my file system, but I'm having some trouble.

I tried typing in the command `mkdir /ruby_tutorials` in a terminal, but I got this error message: 'Permission Denied'. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Because that's what the guide asked me to do...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what guide are you using? I feel pretty dubious about a guide that asks you to create folders off the root.

Comment: i'm using https://learnable.com/courses/learning-ruby-on-rails-3-212/lesson/2/step/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo mkdir /ruby_tutorials
```

`sudo` allows you to execute commands as a [superuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_user). You need administrative privileges to create a directory in your root directory. One reason to use `sudo` for individual commands instead of always having administrative privileges is that it protects you from accidentally harming your system.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, somehow after typing your code this is what happens:


sudo: mkdir/ruby_tutorials: command not found

I created:

def hello_world
  puts "Hello World!"
end

hello_world
--
and put all of that onto a .rtf phone on my mac osx lion

Comment: @Bryan: You need a space in between `mkdir` and `/ruby_tutorials`. There are 3 pieaces: `sudo` (do this as super-user), `mkdir` (make a directory) and `/ruby_tutorials` (the name of the directory to make).

Comment: Thank you Matthew, it says the file exists but the next step doesn't which is "cd /ruby_tutorials". My mac says that the file doesn't exist...

Comment: Tried to delete this post because i submitted a more up-to-date post with more coding lines on it...